# How to prove the Continuity of $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=g(x_1)$

Tags: functions, continuity

I want a help for this question: Let $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ a continuous function. Show that the function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by:
$$f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=g(x_1),$$
is continuous? Thank you.

Comment: What is your approach?

Comment: My approch is to use the definition of continuity of $f$.

Comment: Maybe you could post what you did so far and where you got stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**. Assume $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n) \in \mathbb{R^n}$. One may observe that, for $h=(h_1,\ldots,h_n) \in \mathbb{R^n}$, as $h \to 0$,
$$ 
f(x+h)-f(x)=g(x_1+h_1)-g(x_1)
$$ then one may conclude with the *continuity* of $g$ over $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint : is $\pi_1 : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, $\pi_1(x_1,...,x_n) = x_1$ continuous ?

Comment: Yes because it is a projection.

Comment: Yes ! Now can you express $f$ in function of $g$ and $\pi_1$ ?

Comment: $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=g\circ\pi_1(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$.

Comment: What can you tell about $h\circ g$ when $h$ and $g$ are continuous ?

Comment: $h\circ g$ is continous.